# How to pass variables to LESS parametric mixin for gradient?

Tags: css, macos, less, gradient

This should be a really easy thing to find but I am just not having any luck. I want to create a parametric mixing for a linear gradient, and have some variables with default values that I can change later by passing new variables when I call it. But for some reason it is giving me a syntax error when I try to pass variables.

Here is my mixin:

```
.gradient (@startColor: #adc7e7; @endColor: #ffffff) {
background-color: @endColor;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@startcolor', endColorstr='@endColor', GradientType=1);
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@startColor',endColorstr='@endColor',GradientType=1);
}
```

When I call it like this, it's fine (it just uses the default colors)...

```
.test {background: .gradient; }
```

But when I call it like this to change the from or to colors, I get a syntax error when compiling...

```
.test {background: .gradient(#eeeeee,#ffffff); }
/* semicolon between the values don't work either */
```

I've tried all different ways of writing this and am not having any luck. The LESS documentation does not help at all, it is using @arguments variable which I can't see how to use for a gradient.

I'm using the LESS compiler (from incident57) for mac, version 2.8, build 969.

Answer (score 4):

You should be including your mixin like this:

```
.test {
  .gradient; 
}
```

The following works for me:

```
@blue: blue;
@red: red;

body {
   .gradient(@blue, @red);
}
```

<kbd>[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cyhkp)</kbd>

More details in the [parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-parametric-mixins) doc

Answer (score 0):

### You have Two Main Issues

**First**, you are already including the `background` properties in your mixin, which is *correct* syntax, but makes it *incorrect* to call it like you are as the *value of the property*:

```
.test {background: .gradient(#eeeeee,#ffffff); }
```

Rather, it should be like this:

```
.test {.gradient(#eeeeee,#ffffff); }
```

**Second**, your two `filter` calls need to have the syntax for the variables called differently because they are nested inside of single quotes. So they should change to teh following (note the `{`brackets`}` around the name of the variables):

```
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{startColor}', endColorstr='@{endColor}', GradientType=1);
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{startColor}',endColorstr='@{endColor}',GradientType=1);
```